# Incorrect logical expression: Comparison/SELECT-OPTION can only be followed by "AND","OR" or ")"

Tags: if-statement, abap

I'm writing a program where the idea is, if a date that is given by the user is between 2 constant dates, then it should execute the following code.

But I am getting this syntax error message:

> Incorrect logical expression: Comparison/SELECT-OPTION can only be followed by "AND","OR" or ")"

Code:

```
SELECT-OPTIONS sdate FOR sy-datum DEFAULT '20190816'.

CONSTANTS: date1 TYPE d VALUE '20190101',
           date2 TYPE d VALUE '20191231'.
IF sdate BETWEEN date1 AND date2. " <=== syntax error here
  " do something
ENDIF.
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and why this doesn't work (with error messages) and it will be easier to help.

Comment: There was an error message and code in the post but they were hard to pick out so I tried to better the formatting. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: NB: The error looks non-sense (probably a very old part of the parser that was never modernized). I guess it means that a SELECT-OPTIONS variable used in the left-hand side can only be used in a classic 3-words subexpression (left operand, operator, right operand), the next word can only be "AND", "OR" or ")" for grouping sub-expressions altogether. Note also that you currently test the "[header line](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenheader_line_glosry.htm)" of the SELECT-OPTION, but the visible value is stored in the first line only (see in debug).

Answer (score 3):

You're using `SELECT-OPTIONS`, which does not represent **one date**. It's a range/table containing multiple dates or even date intervals. So it cannot be compared in its whole. You can look at how it looks like in the debugger, maybe that will make it more clear.

Since you only want one input date from the user, you should use `PARAMETERS`.

So instead of using `SELECT-OPTIONS`, you need to use `PARAMETERS` like this:

```
DATA: date1 TYPE d VALUE '20190101',
      date2 TYPE d VALUE '20191231'.

PARAMETERS input_d TYPE d.

IF input_d BETWEEN date1 AND date2.
  "do something
ENDIF.
```